# Custom template for 3 level url

Tags: ee2

How to make custom template for entry?
Example:
site.com/service/repair/
I have 2 entry about repair. iPhone repair & iPad repair
So how to make page with url
site.com/service/repair/iphone-repair
and unique template for this page?

Answer (score 1):

[Switchee](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) by Mark Croxton would be of use here:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_3}" parse="inward"}

{!-- Index page. Match empty string or pagination --}
{case value="phone"} 
    phone page
{/case}

{!-- Single entry --}
{case default="yes"}
    pad
{/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

If you need to match an empty string or use pagination, use it like this:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_3}" parse="inward"}

{!-- Index page. Match empty string or pagination --}
{case value="#^P(\d+)$#|''"}
    Index page
{/case}

{!-- Single entry --}
{case default="yes"}
    Single entry
{/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just make 1 template, with a route of `service\repair\{any}`. This template then gets all URL's with first 2 segemetns of /service/repair...

Then you cna switch on the `segment_3`, like so :

```
{if segment_3 == 'iphone-repair'}
  {embed="partials/iphone-specific"}
{if:elseif segment_3 == 'ipad-repair'}
  {embed="partials/ipad-specific"} 
{if:else}
  {embed="partials/mobile-generic"}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another slightly different way, in your "repair" template:

```
{if segment_3 == ""}
  Your content for service/repair
{if:else}
  Your content for service/repair/iphone-repair (where segment 3 has a url_title)
{/if}
```